# Local Git branch not pushing successfully to remote

Tags: git, branch, push, git-remote

I am facing a problem with git push. I had created a new branch, created a new file and committed it with a comment. Then I did a `git push origin master`. I see the changes on github.

But when I do a `git push`, it does not send the changes to the remote repo, i.e. remote work-repo (https://github.com//work-repo.git).

```
$ git status
# On branch mybranch
nothing to commit (working directory clean)

$ git push
Counting objects: 16, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (6/6), done.
Writing objects: 100% (6/6), 607 bytes, done.
Total 6 (delta 5), reused 0 (delta 0)
To https://github.com/<myuser>/work-repo.git
   16ff794..55e4338  master -> master
```

When I go over to www github, and try to do a 'Pull Request' on the remote work-repo, I see there are multiple commits (from my other git branches + this current branch), and I cannot select just this one in this Pull Request.

Earlier, for other branches, `git push` was working fine and it sent out the changes to the remote work-repo. I don't know what is the issue this time.

What should I check?

**Update:**

When I do a `git push -u origin <your_local_branch_name>:<your_remote_branch_name>`, I get this msg:

```
git push -u origin mybranch:master
To https://github.com/<myuser>/work-repo.git 
! [rejected] mybranch -> master (non-fast-forward) 
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/<myuser>/work-repo.git' 
hint: Updates were rejected because a pushed branch tip is behind its remote 
hint: counterpart. Check out this branch and merge the remote changes 
hint: (e.g. 'git pull') before pushing again. 
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

**Update:**
Since I couldn't figure this out & didn't get any responses, I cleaned up the repo and forked fresh from remote and started again.

**Mods**: Please close this question now.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
git push -u origin <your_local_branch_name>:<your_remote_branch_name>
```

-u flag makes your local branch trackable, so next time it will know where to push if you just do `git push origin`.